# Dell Sputnik to launch in the UK?

Tags: dell

Does anyone know if Dell is to release the Dell XPS 13 Laptop, Developer Edition, running Ubuntu 12.04LTS – code named project Sputnik – in the United Kingdom? 
If so, does anyone know when?

Comment: is it oem pc what coming with ubuntu ?

Comment: "Can’t wait until fall to get one?
Create your own now. Purchase a Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook™ (which comes with the Microsoft® Windows® operating system preloaded) and download the Ubuntu image and drivers from the website of our partner Canonical." http://www.dell.com/uk/business/p/d/campaigns/sputnik

Comment: They have issued a launch date.
Dell XPS 13 Laptop, Developer Edition -- a client-to-cloud solution (formerly project Sputnik) with great juju support is due to be released in the UK in March. 

This is a very exciting time for Ubuntu and developers.

Comment: It's available now - costs £899. http://www.dell.com/uk/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd.aspx?s=bsd